# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure when trying to run my project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to follow this tutorial, my program has the API template

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

but when I run the program it gives me this error HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

it also says 
The application to execute does not exist: 'C:\Users\Cristina\Desktop\roweb proj\TodoApi\TodoApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\TodoApi.dll'
even though it did not create those files when I created the folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons as to why this error may arise.

Call your .dll file of your project in the cmd using the dotnet command will help you understand exactly what the issue is. In my case there was a version error for ASP.NET core. Make sure all your project dependencies in the .csproj file of your project use the same version of ASP.NET core SDK and runtime bundle. You can check the versions present on your system through the dotnet command on cmd:

```
dotnet --info
```

Take a moment to read this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/945), there may be a solution for your problem .